# Why does Safari display the letter combination 'fi' as 'if'?

Tags: display, safari, font

I just came across a curious display error and was wondering what may cause it.

In Safari the following webpage [Cross-Country Skating](https://skiinghistory.org/history/cross-country-skating-how-it-started): shows a strange behaviour.

[image]     [image]

But the source code does not show this error:

```
... America’s Bill Koch first observed ...
... climaxing in a telegenic finish ...
```

Neither does Google Chrome:

[image]    [image]

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

---

System:
MacBook Air (MacBookAir3,1)
Intel Core 2 Duo; 1,6 GHz

OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)

Safari Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9)

Comment: Note that Firefox displays it like Safari does too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an official bug, yes. It seems to be solely happening with Merriweather Sans.

Maybe someone at Apple or on the east coast decided to protest the name of the font? ;)

Seriously, an update is in the works, and someone here suggests a work-around.

https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/184

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a problem with Safari font rendering engine with Merriweather Sans font. It has something to do with [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) I suppose. You can check [typecast.com](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Merriweather%20Sans) and see that when You insert `fi` it automatically is changed to `if` as You type.

Comment: I thought so too. The error occurs throughout the article ligatures might be the combining factor. But do you have an idea what causes this ligature misrepresentation?